# Extract userInfo from JSCH stream

Tags: jsch

I am trying to implement an online terminal UI with jsch as backend.
I need to display the userinfo ie [username@Machine ~]$ information in the UI.
Since the outputstream simply sends the bytes, it is difficult to distinguish the userinfo with the real command output. Is there any way to distinguish the same?

Answer (score 1):

In general, no.

If you have a shell channel, all you see is the output from the user's remote shell, including the prompt and the actual command output. You can try to parse that. In simple cases this will work, but in general it is impossible, as every command could output a prompt-like string.

The username should be known to you (it should be the same as you used for login), the server name is a bit trickier.

An idea worth exploring might be to set a special prompt delimited by character sequences which are unlikely to occur in "normal" command output – set the `PROMPT` variable in your shell.

You could circumvent that problem by not using actually a `shell` channel, but an individual `exec` channel for each command – but then you'll have to interpret commands like `cd` yourself and keep track of the current directory, and add a `cd` command before the actual command in each exec channel. You might want to have an sftp channel open in parallel to keep track of the directories (and list files, and so on).